# On NSWindowController, setting contentViewController updates the window's position, how can I stop this?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nswindow, nswindowcontroller

I have a `NSWindowController` with an `NSWindow`, 
I am having an issue where, if I set the controller's `contentViewController`, the frame of the `NSWindow` updates beyond my expectations

1. Window is at a origin, say (500,500), and size is (100,100)
2. I drag it to (300,300)
3. I press a control which updates `contentViewController`
4. The size remains at (100,100), but the
   origin goes back to (500, 500)

The entire window remains the same size, but it just moves back to the original position

This is the code that updates the frame

```
self.contentViewController = loadingViewController
```

I confirmed this by printing out the window's frame in lldb, before and after this line:

```
▿ Optional<CGRect>
  ▿ some : (-1701.0, 439.0, 1042.0, 778.0)
    ▿ origin : (-1701.0, 439.0)
      - x : -1701.0
      - y : 439.0
    ▿ size : (1042.0, 778.0)
      - width : 1042.0
      - height : 778.0

(lldb) po self.window?.frame
▿ Optional<CGRect>
  ▿ some : (-1680.0, 416.0, 800.0, 778.0)
    ▿ origin : (-1680.0, 416.0)
      - x : -1680.0
      - y : 416.0
    ▿ size : (1042.0, 778.0)
      - width : 1042.0
      - height : 778.0
```

What is even more mysterious, is that I originally tried 3 separate places to catch the window moving to locate the line of code causing it

I registered as an observer:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(windowMoved(notification:)), name: NSWindow.didMoveNotification, object: nil)
```

as well as setting symbolic breakpoints on:

-[NSWindow _windowMoved:]
and
-[NSWindow _setFrame:]

All 3 of these methods caught window movement when I manually dragged the window around.

However, none of the 3 caught the window moving when the frame was changed programmatically from that one line of code above ^^

Has anybody seen this before, or have an idea of how this could be?

Comment: How can we reproduce the issue in a test project?

Comment: oo that's a good point.  I'm about out of ideas, especially because I can't catch the window's frame changing instruction, I can only see it visually change.  I'll try to pull it out, isolate it into a test project and if I can figure out the issue I'll report back.  Otherwise I'll just upload the test project for you guys to check out

Answer (score 2):

Turned out to be too much effort to isolate this issue into a test project, so I decided to just put a patch in,

I just store the origin before setting the `contentViewController`, and reset it afterwards.  This works for me, though I'm still unsure why this is happening

```
    let originalFrameOrigin = self.window?.frame.origin ?? CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)
    self.contentViewController = loadingViewController
    self.window?.setFrameOrigin(originalFrameOrigin)
```

Comment: I ran in to this issue and came to the same conclusion but I now realise that in full screen mode changing the contentViewController causes the top of the contentView to be clipped - although set up with a top space to superview = 0 constraint, it's positioning the top of the nsview UNDER the nstoolbar. Did you run in to that issue and if so find a fix?

Comment: Just tested it, I went full-screen and tried swapping out the main viewcontroller via our UI, and that didn't happen.  *However*, I have seen that before, and that was related to autolayout constraints.  Hopefully interface builder can help you, but I think you'll need to add some room into your content view, sounds like your subviews are getting squooshed in somehow

Comment: My bad – it was because I was setting the size as well as the position of the frame (though why setting the size based on the size of the previous contentviewcontroller frame caused the issue is beyond me). In the end I just added a check for fullscreen mode and only reset the frame when it's not active.

Comment: Nice.  Yeah it's a little funny, with my aforementioned issue, we only saw that on macOS 10.13, where the view would go under the toolbar.  On 10.14 it wasn't a problem